# XERCES: Warning'и при компиляции (LNK4217, LNK4049)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

При компиляции проекта, который использует Xerces валятся warning'и.

```
1>RequestServiceOnXMLHelpers.obj : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol ??1MemBufInputSource@xercesc_3_2@@UAE@XZ (public: virtual __thiscall xercesc_3_2::MemBufInputSource::~MemBufInputSource(void)) imported in function "void __cdecl RequestService::DoRequestWithStreamXMLResponse(struct XMLTransport::IXMLTransport *,struct Common::IDebugTextGetterControlForPauser *,class XML::CRequestHolder &,class XML::CStreamXMLContentHandler &)" (?DoRequestWithStreamXMLResponse@RequestService@@YAXPAUIXMLTransport@XMLTransport@@PAUIDebugTextGetterControlForPauser@Common@@AAVCRequestHolder@XML@@AAVCStreamXMLContentHandler@7@@Z)
```

Непонятно, что с этим можно сделать.
Гугл советует в опции препроцессора добавлять параметры XML_LIBRARY или XERCES_STATIC_LIBRARY, но ни то, ни то не помогает убрать предупреждения.

Может быть кто-нибудь сталкивался.